# Gstreamer - using a variable for video path

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gstreamer

I have a question concerning Gstreamer and the path for the video (uri).
Indeed, in order to try my code, I used to set the path to my video directly in the C++ source code, that way :

```
data.pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("playbin2 uri=file:///D:/video", NULL);
```

But now, I am using a user interface (wxWidgets) in order to get the path to the video that the user wants to play. The path is now in a variable, m_txtVideoPath. And I don't know how I can launch the video using this variable, instead of D:/video.

Thanks in advance for your answer !

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you mean that when the variable gets chosen it's a relative path and not an absolute path to the video?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, when I wanted to play a video, I used to set the path like that :
 data.pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("playbin2 uri=file:///D:/video", NULL);
But I'd like to use the variable m_txtVideoPath which contains D:\video, which is an absolute path too.
So the first problem is that there is a difference between / and \.
And then, I don't know how I can use the variable instead of uri=file:///D:/video (I mean the syntax I have to use)

Comment: Are you concatenating the strings "playbin2 uri=file://" and m_txtVideoPath and then passing the combined string to gst_parse_launch?

Comment: Yes, it is the idea. I don't know if it is the easiest way of doing it, but it is what I want to do. However, I tried and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to construct the pipeline with the user-defined filename, rather than hardcode everything.

this is very basic string handling, you might want to consult a beginner's tutorial for your programming language of choice.

e.g.

```
 std::string pipeline = "playbin2";
 pipeline+=" uri=file://"+m_txtVideoPath;
 std::cout << "PIPELINE: " << pipeline << std::endl; // for debugging
 data.pipeline = gst_parse_launch (pipeline.c_str(), NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you umlaeute, that works very good. This is very helpful for me.
I will consult a beginner's tutorial in order to get more information about this particular point.